Who or what did Ed transmute in episode 63 before meeting the Truth?
When Edward performed his last transmutation using the human transmutation circle, who/what did he transmute before he got to meet the Truth again?

He met Truth because he was transmuting Alphonse back into existence in exchange for his own alchemy door. No need for a second transmutation.
